# How to use grails withForm through ajax call

Tags: ajax, grails, transactions, hibernate-mapping, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.5.2 version. I have a form submit event by ajax call where sometimes form is submitted multiple times. I have goggled for it and see about grails withForm topic. I tried to implement it but it stops the request for the first time and show invalid token message. How can I use useToken for withForm or other way to stop multiple time form submit via ajax call in grails.

My code attempts are below.

My ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:'JSON',
                    data: $("#createFormModal").serialize(),
                    url: "${g.createLink(controller: 'studentCollection', action: 'save')}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data.isError==true){
                            showAlertModal(data.message);
                        }else {
                            $('#createModal').modal('hide');
                            $('#list-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                            showSuccessMsg(data.message);
                            $("#createFormModal").find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    }
                });
```

My controller method:

```
def save() {
    LinkedHashMap result = new LinkedHashMap()
    String outPut

    withForm {
        result = studentCollectionService.saveCollection(params)
    }.invalidToken {
        println("### invalidate Token")
        result.put(CommonUtils.IS_ERROR, Boolean.TRUE)
        result.put(CommonUtils.MESSAGE, "Please press the button once")
    }

    outPut = result as JSON
    render outPut
    return
}
```

Comment: Does `$("#createFormModal").serialize()` contain the token?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown no it does not

Comment: if I provide one then won't it be use twice like `abc` or what should be the key name if I provide like - `token: abcd`

Comment: "if I provide one then won't it be use twice like abc or what should be the key name if I provide like - token: abcd" - No.  The token may be submitted any number of times but will only be accepted once, which is the goal.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I will try it. Which name should I use for token params - `token` or something else

Comment: `"Which name should I use for token params - token or something else"` - Something else.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/773516041db6c1a90cf2bd0f2e1ff4291dd71264/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy#L364-L370.  That generates a hidden form field for the token when using `<g:form useToken="true" ... />` in a GSP.  If you want the built in token validation stuff to work you need to use the same key that is using and use the `SynchronizerTokensHolder` to generate the token.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown my source code modification would be a great help